# VueJS: $_FILES Not Receiving Data from Frontend to Backend

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I tried different ways to upload images to SQL, but the problem is that I cannot get the file's data at backend. Some answers say that it's because the form does not have an enctype but I tried that too. I'm not sure if it's applicable to Vue since I am using axios. Also, I tried using uploadFile as a parameter for the axios so $_FILES would also read it as $_GET, because it worked on some of my codes as well. By the way, the submitTestData is in another file in another folder, which is inside a store (VueX). I used dispatch to send the data towards the store so that it would finally send a post method to backend.

store.js

```
  submitTestData2 ({ commit }, payload) {
        console.log(payload.uploadFile)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const formData = new FormData()
          formData.append('uploadFile', payload.uploadFile)
          const config = {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
          }
          axios
            .post(
              'http://localhost/MyComposer/',
              {
                token: payload.token,
                subject: payload.subject,
                timer: payload.timer,
                question: payload.question,
                answer: payload.answer,
                formData
              },
              {
                params: {
                  submitId: 7,
                  uploadFile: formData
                },
                config
              }
            )
            .then(response => {
              commit('SAVE_TEST_DATA', response.data)
              console.log(response)
              resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              reject(error)
            })
        })
      },
```

AddTest.vue

```
 <q-form class="q-pa-md" align="center">
        <h5>Test Creation Form</h5>
        <!-- <q-btn label="Add Subject" color="primary" to="/addsub" /> -->
        <q-btn label="Return to Main" to="/dashboard" color="primary" />&nbsp;
        <q-btn label="View Student Answers" color="primary" to="/subjectntestlist" />&nbsp;
        <q-btn label="View Student Profile" color="primary" to="/studentprofile" />
        <q-card>
          <q-separator />
          <q-card-section class="q-gutter-md" align="center">
            <q-select
              filled
              v-model="testItems.subject"
              :options="option"
              map-options
              emit-value
              option-value="subjectId"
              option-label="subjectName"
              label="Choose a Subject"
              style="width: 250px"
              stack-label
              input-debounce="0"
            />
            <q-file
              filled
              v-model="testItems.uploadFile"
              label="Upload File Here"
              style="width: 500px"
            />
            <h5>Timer</h5>
            <q-input label="Minute(s)" name="timer" v-model="testItems.timer" style="width: 500px" />
            <h5>Question</h5>
            <q-input name="question" v-model="testItems.question" style="width: 500px" />
            <h5>Answer</h5>
            <q-input name="answer" v-model="testItems.answer" style="width: 500px" />
            <br />
            <q-btn label="Save Test Item" @click="submitTestData" />
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
      </q-form>

submitTestData1() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("submitTestData2", {
          token: this.token,
          subject: this.testItems.subject,
          question: this.testItems.question,
          answer: this.testItems.answer,
          uploadFile: this.testItems.uploadFile,
          timer: this.testItems.timer
        })
        .then(response => {
          alert("Test was added to the database!");
        });
    },
```

```
<?php

namespace Classes;

use Classes\ConnectDb;

class TestClass
{
    public function addTest()
    {
        $datab = new ConnectDb;
        $db = $datab->Connect();


        if (isset($_GET['submitId']) && $_GET['submitId'] == 7) {

            $testdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $testdecodedData = json_decode($testdata);
            $subject = $testdecodedData->{'subject'};
            $access_id = $testdecodedData->{'token'};
            $question = $testdecodedData->{'question'};
            $answer = $testdecodedData->{'answer'};
            // $testImage = $testdecodedData->{'uploadFile'};
            $testTimer = $testdecodedData->{'timer'};

            $name = $_FILES['uploadFile'];

            echo $name;

            $testdataDb = array(
                'SubjectId' => $subject,
                'AccessId' => $access_id,
                'Question' => $question,
                'Answer' => $answer,
                // 'TestImage' => $testImage,
                'Timer' => $testTimer * 60
            );
            $testId = $db->insert('testdetails', $testdataDb);
            if ($testId) {
                echo 'Test details were added!';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've got `@click="submitTestData"` but your `submitTestData` looks like a Vuex action. Where are you passing in `payload`?

Comment: Sorry about not pasting the entire code. I updated the question now. the submitTestData had the same name. One for dispatching, and one for Axios post request. Now I added a number so you can see the flow now.

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to tweak my backend a bit. It finally works. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass header as well like below

```
submitTestData ({ commit }, payload) {
    console.log(payload.uploadFile)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('uploadFile', payload.uploadFile)
      const config = {
            headers:{'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'}
       };
      axios
        .post('http://localhost/MyComposer/',formData,config)
        .then(response => {
          commit('SAVE_TEST_DATA', response.data)
          console.log(response)
          resolve(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error)
        })
    })
  },
```

Comment: Still not working for me. Your answer makes sense though, so I'm adding it to my codes. Should I use the uploadFile in append as the name inside $_FILES?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not getting the file's name properly from the $_FILES superglobal. You have $_FILES['uploadFile'] in your code however the $_FILES array is structured like this for uploads (*uploadFile represents the name of the file upload input field from your form so this varies by input field name*):

```
Array
(
    [uploadFile] => Array
            (
                      [name] => users_file_name.png
                      [type] => image/png
                      [tmp_name] => /path/to/temporary/files/abc123
                      [error] => 0
                      [size] => 12345
            )
)
```

So to access the file's name, you need to change the code to this: $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'].

The actual file is stored in a temporary file location on the server so you'll need to grab that temporary file and move it somewhere else on your server. Something like this is what most people do:

```
$temp_file = $_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
$target_upload_destination = 'path/to/desired/directory/' . basename($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);

// Check to see that the file was moved to desired destination successfully
if (move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $target_upload_destination)) {
      // do something here
    } else {
      // Fallback logic here
}
```

Obviously there should be some logic checks before moving the temp file on your server but, I hope you get the basic idea behind this. You should use the file path once it's moved for the DB insert. I hope this helps.

Comment: I edited the submitTestData method based on the answer here.  Do you think it is compatible with your answer or do I need to add 'name' in the formData.append as well?

Comment: This is just for the server-side of things in PHP. Anku's answer about the headers was a good catch. Did you try printing the $_FILES array after an upload to see if anything is being set at all? If the array is empty, there is an issue in what is being passed over. For debugging try this:

print_r($_FILES);

Comment: Based from the request payload, the formData (recently uploadFile) is an empty object. And yes, the array is empty, so what should I do now?

Comment: Did some digging and looks like you're using quasar with vue right? If so I found this little tip:
"When dealing with a native form which has an action and a method (eg. when using Quasar with ASP.NET controllers), you need to specify the name property on QFile, otherwise formData will not contain it (if it should):", can you try giving that input field a name, the same name in your PHP code "uploadFile"?

https://quasar.dev/vue-components/file-picker#Native-form-submit

Comment: Does append work if the submitTestData is on a different file? In VueJS, I added it to the store for better management. Maybe it doesn't read it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here both in your client-side and server-side code.

#### Client side

If you want to send a file, you must use a `multipart/form-data` request with a `FormData` payload. You appear to be trying to combine a JSON payload with an embedded `FormData` which simply won't work.

You need something like this

```js
const formData = new FormData()
Object.entries(payload).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  // adds all the properties in "payload" to "formData"
  formData.append(key, val)
})

axios.post('http://localhost/MyComposer', formData, {
  params: { submitId: 7 }
})
```

❗ Note that there is no `Content-type` header added. Passing a `FormData` instance sets this automatically with the required mime boundaries.

#### Server-side

On the PHP side, you would get the `token`, `subject`, `timer`, etc values from `$_POST`

```php
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$access_id = $_POST['token'];
$question = $_POST['question'];
// etc
```

The upload file will be available in `$_FILES` (see https://www.php.net/manual/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

```php
$uploadFile = $_FILES['uploadFile'];
if (!$uploadFile['error']) {
  echo $uploadFile['name'];
}
```

Comment: Still won't work for me :( . I even placed a name="uploadFile" on the q-file just to make it stick with append.

Comment: What exactly _"isn't working"_? Is your PHP environment actually set up to allow file uploads?

Comment: @Codebuddy7 That doesn't answer either of my questions. Q1 - What _"isn't working"_? Q2 - Have you tried a simple upload test using PostMan or something like that? Have you configured all the required PHP settings for enabling file uploads?

Comment: Q1 - The FormData is not working, therefore it is passing an empty object as a request payload.. Q2 - I tried a Native PHP file upload, but it won't work if $_FILES doesnt get any data.

Comment: _"The FormData is not working"_  what **exactly** does this mean?

Comment: If you're trying a file upload via PostMan and `$_FILES` is still empty, then it's a good chance your PHP environment is misconfigured. See the note in the documentation - [Related Configurations Note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#features.file-upload.post-method)

Comment: I'm not using PostMan. I'm using MySQL.

Comment: [Postman](https://www.postman.com/product/api-client/) is a tool for testing APIs. It's not a database

Comment: Managed to make it work after a few tweaks. Thanks so much for the help. And sorry for being so confusing with my questions lately, I'm still new at programming and I hope I would be clearer and straightforward with my questions next time